# CSS Mobile menu designs

Tags: css, menu

Hi and thanks in advance.

I'm struggling with the correct CSS Code to change only the Mobile Menu colors...

I want to change (Only in mobile, without affecting the desktop site) the placeholder text and the drop-down menu text and background.

Any ideas?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: you have a free wordpress site? can you paste your own CSS on it?

Comment: Yes, can you provide me the CSS Code for resolve my problem or just..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in [your css file](https://oceantos.com/javascripts/assets/css/ico_isometric/main.css), you gotta override or change this class (which is causing the navigation links to disappear on a burger menu:

```
#header .stm-header .stm-header__cell .stm-icontext__text, #header .stm-header .stm-header__cell a:not(.stm_btn) {
    color: #26211d!important;
}
```

you can do:

```
@media screen and (max-width:1023px) {
    #header .stm-header .stm-header__cell a:not(.stm_btn) {
            color: #fff !important;
    }
}
```

in addition to the color property, you can change other aspects (background, border, padding, margins etc.) too

UPDATE: background of the dropdown menu

```
.stm-header__hb .stm-navigation__default>ul>li ul.sub-menu {
            background: lightblue;
    }
```

Comment: Yes but without changing also the Dropdown menu it doesnt will works to me..
How can i change the dropdown menu colors? Thank you mate.

Comment: @MichaelThomson, my bad... forgot the brackets around max-width... `@media screen and (max-width:1023px) `; updated the answer, kindly check now.

Comment: Without changing also the Dropdown menu it doesnt will works to me.. How can i change the dropdown menu colors? Thank you mate.

Comment: Im mean the placeholder text and background of the Drop down menu only

Comment: background color of the dropdown menu on desktop only?

Comment: Desktop and mobile as well

Comment: `.stm-header__hb .stm-navigation__default>ul>li ul.sub-menu {
            background: lightblue;
    }` this should work... let me know if anything